# lua : string to table by some criteria

Tags: string, csv, lua, datatable

I have csv file and I want to change each line to table

csv format like this

case1) 564186207,399.4989929,3317.988037,7287824519535926300,32,30,17,17,0,50000,50000

case2) 8916.1350 8986.6161 15.8202   993332    Warning2_CONEDGE  INS_ADI_BOTVIA_DUAL_ENC

I want to this line to change table

case1) {564186207, 399.4989929, 3317.988037, 7287824519535926300, 32, 30, 17, 17, 0, 50000, 50000 }

case2) {8916.1350, 8986.6161, 15.8202,   993332,    Warning2_CONEDGE,  INS_ADI_BOTVIA_DUAL_ENC }

How can I chage like that by lua ?

I tried it as string.find or string.gfind. but it's usage is difficult. and I don't have engough knowledge of string pattern match concept.

Help me please

Comment: Actually, I am really new of the lua. Even this answer is difficult to me. but I will study that and try it. it's so helpful. thank you so much